# Authenticating Developers with APIKey and Users with BasicAuth/OAuth

Tags: python, django, api, rest, tastypie

I've looked around for this but can't seem to find a canonical answer. I'm trying to follow best practices. Maybe I'm thinking of it the wrong way.

I'm thinking of my API users as two different types: developers and end users, with separate django models in separate applications.

Developers will build clients for the API, and have access to certain resources of the API without the need of users login in. To limit their access, I would require them to register and in exchange give them an API key. We would also dogfood this to say, build a site frontend using Angular and iOS app.
Once those developers build their API clients, users of my site, which have already created a user account, will use the API clients created by developers. In the request from those clients I would expect a developer name, api_key as well as username/password (digest, if its our own trusted client and oauth token for thid party developers). This will require to check 1) developers are allowed to use the API by checking their APIKey, and 2) authenticate the end user. Is this possible in tastypie?

Am I going about this the wrong way? How would I do the double authentication?

Answer (score 1):

We run a production site with this exact scheme. Of course you'll have to do your own tunning. But the general idea is good. You could have some OAuth inplace too, but we've found that it's not worth it. OAuth is too complicated for most cases.

I'll explain roughly what we do.

**This is the App/developers part:**

1. We identify "apps" (iOS, Android, BB, the site). Each app has an ApiClient instance model. The ApiClient has three attrs: name, public key, and private key.
2. We exchange the public and private keys through a safe channel with the ApiClient owner (the app).
3. The app must send every request indicating the public key and a signature generated with the private key (using hmac).
4. Everytime we get a request, we get the public key from the request, look it up in the DB, see what App it belongs too (the name) and check the signature. If everything is ok, the request is fulfilled.

**For the user authentication part:**

1. To authenticate a user we use other model ApiKey (provided by tastypie). Each user has an ApiKey. That model stores a unique (we could say random) string. When the user gets to the app he/she logs in into your API. The app should issue a request similar to this one:

   POST /api/v1/login/
   {
       'username': 'XXX',
       'password': 'XXX'
   }

   (please note that it always need to pass the previous public/private key auth)
2. If the user provided the right credentials we return an ApiKey unique key.
3. Every following request made by the app in behave of that user must include the key. That's the way you identify which user is trying to do each action.

**An example of this last part:**

1. User Jon logs in in the iOS app. (using regular username and password)
2. The app sends the request:

   POST /api/v1/login/
   {
       'username': 'jon',
       'password': 'snow'
   }
3. We have a `login` API method. We check if the user exists and if the pass is ok. Suppose it's ok.
4. We sent the ApiKey info:

   200 OK
   {
       'username': 'jon',
       'key': '$123$'
   }
5. The app has authenticated the user. It needs to use those credentials.
6. The user tries to do something in your app. Suppose he tries to get the datetime from your app. The app will issue this request:

   GET /api/v1/date/

   Authorization: ApiKey jon:$123$

That's it. It's not super safe. The ApiKeys are not invalidated. But that's because we create our own internal Apps. It's worth to note that we borrow some stuff from Tastypie from this. Check this out: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html#apikeyauthentication

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response, that was very helpful as a sanity check. You essentially use the API keys in lieu of sessions, which is probably not as secure or easy to manage, but works. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is tangental, but you may want to check out [drf-keypair-permissions](https://pypi.org/project/drf-keypair-permissions/).

It's a Django module that uses asymmetric public/private keypairs to sign and verify the HTTP request using pre-shared keys. It can pair each public key with a user so the authorization doubles as a login, and can be extended to manage API throttling.

It supports a few algorithms, including RSA-SHA and elliptic curve, and keys can be managed in the admin area.
[image]

It uses the [IETC Cavage-12 draft standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-cavage-http-signatures-12#appendix-E.2) for processing the Authorization signature